# delete all folders and files within a linux directory except one folder and all contents inside that folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, directory

I have a directory structure as :-

```
/usr/testing/member/
   ---> public--->folder1--->file1
           \----> file2
   ---> folder3:- contains files and folders
   ---> folder4:- contains files and folders
   ---> several files
```

I want to keep the public folder and all its contents (further folders and files within it) but want to delete everything else under the directory /usr/testing/member/. But that also means member folder is not deleted.
Is there any shell script or command that can be used to achieve this exactly as i stated.

Comment: What have you tried? Most of us here are happy to help you improve your craft, but are less happy acting as short order unpaid programming staff.  Review [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), show us your work so far in an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the result you were expecting and the results you got, and we'll help you figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
(cd /usr/testing/member; find . -maxdepth 1 \( ! -name . -a ! -name public \) -exec echo rm -fr {} +)
```

That is: `cd` into `/usr/testing/member`, find all files and directories there, without going further below, and exclude the current directory (".") and any file or directory named "public", and execute a command for the found files.

This will print what would be deleted.
Verify it looks good, and then drop the `echo`.

Answer (score 0):

I think below will do the work,

```
$ cd  /usr/testing/member/
$ rm -rf $(ls | grep -v "public")
```

**explanation:**

we are passing everything inside `/usr/testing/member/` but `public` to `rm` by making use of  `-v(exclude)` option of `grep`

Comment: But this one doesn't delete the files within /usr/testing/member/

Comment: Sorry, but i am pretty sure, It will delete both files & directories inside "/usr/testing/member/" except "public" directory and its sub contents.
i don't see a reason why it wont delete files particularly.

Comment: yeah you can create any sample directory structure and try yourself, it deletes all folders and their contents except for public which is fine, but then doesn't delete the files that are also in there under /usr/testing/member

Comment: Sorry to disagree,  but i am damn sure it will delete both files & directories inside "/usr/testing/member/" except "public" directory.

Comment: Just created a directory structure, with files all over and everything is deleted except public.  It works, upvote.

Comment: It will also miss `/usr/testing/member/foo/public_html/`, and will fail noisily (and perhaps dangerously) if any files contain spaces, or newlines in their names. It's never a good idea to [parse ls](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Even if it works in certain cases, it develops bad habits that could bite you hard in the future.